# Implementing Ripple Effect in Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to add this Ripple effect on my toolbar https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect but currently I'm lost on how to do this.

base on how to add toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/app_secondary_color" 
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" > 
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then setting in Activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_login);
```

Where should I put this

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
  android:id="@+id/more"
  android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  ripple:rv_centered="true">


</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

Comment: have you included the library in your build path?

Comment: yes. I used it on my button. I just don't know how to use it on Toolbar

Comment: is it working on button? I just tried on textview it working...

Comment: yups its.working. How did you use it with toolbar?

Comment: are you using toolbar as actionbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
 android:id="@+id/more"
 android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
 android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
 android:layout_margin="5dp"
 ripple:rv_centered="false">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/app_secondary_color" 
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" > 
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

Also do not forget to include this in your root layout.

```
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

In your mainActivity(if toolbar is your action bar):

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Comment: thanks bud. its working but the whole actionbar has it ripple effect

Comment: is there a way the ripple effect just work with action buttons?

Comment: i have not tried it, but try adding the RippleView to your action buttons(in the xml where button exists, eg main.xml) in the same way you applied it to the toolbar.