# status bar font color not changing synchronously

Tags: android

I am changing the `decorView` of my `window` to basically toggle between `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` being true and false depending upon a scroll position of my view.

Since I am changing the ActionBar and the status Bar at the same time, I would like both changes to at least be perceptibly instantaneous. However I notice there is a 50ms delay between `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = newIntWithToggledLightMode` being executed and the new status bar mode being rendered. I don't want to have my toolbar changes be placed in a postDelay handler just to coordinate their appearance of simultaneity with the status bar change. I thought I could override `onSystemUiVisibilityChangeInterface` to be informed when the status bar ui had been updated but that only seems triggered when I make the status bar invisible, not simply changing the appearance mode. Has anybody run into this and come up with a more elegant solution?

Comment: What looks more elegant would be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28356400/7910454) (see question for a gif).

Comment: @MiXT4PE thank you for the suggestion, however the circular reveal in the answer you linked only changes the statusbar background, but does not change the status bar font color. It is the latter that has the asynchronous UI update, not the former. thus my question still stands :)

Comment: Have you considered use transculent status bar? In that way you would only have to change the action bar color and not both.

Comment: @OmerCohen1994 that is orthogonal to the underlying issue. You are right it may be easier to change the bg's of both status and action bar but the problem is changing the text color of the status bar, which has to be through the decorView's systemUiVisibility flags. That problem would not be solved by making the status bar translucent.

Answer (score 1):

I just investigated trying to replicate your issue, but I did not encountered the latency that you are talking about... In my example, I simulated the changing background event with a button click. Hoping that it will help you, I share my code here:

**activity's attribute**

```
private val isLight get () = (window.decorView.systemUiVisibility and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR) > 0
```

**button initialization in activity's onCreate**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (isLight) {
        setStatusBarColors(
            decorView.systemUiVisibility and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv(),
            ContextCompat.getColor(decorView.context, android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
        )
    } else {
        setStatusBarColors(
            decorView.systemUiVisibility or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR,
            ContextCompat.getColor(decorView.context, android.R.color.holo_red_light)
        )
    }
}
```

**and the *setStatusBarColors()* function**

```
private fun setStatusBarColors(flags: Int, @ColorInt bgColor: Int) {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
    window.statusBarColor = bgColor
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(bgColor)
}
```

This code lead to the following result (click on the following GIF if it does not run):
[image]

Comment: it is pretty subtle but you can see the difference if you offset the bg of action and status bar changing after 50ms then you see it happens at the exact same time as the status bar text color change.